# How do I run this MySQL JOIN query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Let's say I have 2 tables.

The first table is a list of personas. A user can have many personas.

```
mysql> select id, user_id, name from personas_personas;
+----+---------+--------------+
| id | user_id | name         |
+----+---------+--------------+
|  8 |       1 | startup      |
|  9 |       1 | nerd         |
| 10 |       1 | close        |
| 12 |       2 | Nerd         |
| 13 |       2 | Startup      |
| 14 |       2 | Photographer |
+----+---------+--------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, I have another table called "approvals".

```
mysql> select id, from_user_id, to_user_id, persona_id  from friends_approvals;
+----+--------------+------------+------------+
| id | from_user_id | to_user_id | persona_id |
+----+--------------+------------+------------+
|  2 |            1 |          2 |          8 |
|  3 |            1 |          2 |          9 |
+----+--------------+------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If `from_user` wants to approve `to_user` to a persona, then a record is inserted.

I'm trying to do this query...

Given a user, find all its personas.  Then, for each persona, determine if it's approved for a certain `to_user`.  If so, return `is_approved`=1 in the result set. Otherwise, return `is_approved`=0 in the result set.

So this is where I start:

```
SELECT *
FROM personas_personas
WHERE user_id = 1
LEFT JOIN friends_approvals ON
...but i don't know where to go from here.
```

So, the final result set should have all the columns in the `personas_personas` table, and then also `is_approved` for each of the results.

Comment: FYI, you should have a User, Persona and a UserPersona table (for better normalization). Then maybe a UserPersonaUser table with all the "approvals".

Comment: @BradChristie  I have a User table and a Persona Table.  Why do I need  UserPersona table?

Comment: Avoids duplicate personas. Once persona "XYZ" is is the persona table it can't be duplicated, just simply re-assigned/used. UserPersonal would be a Many-to-Many relationship. (unless i missunderstand the scheme--entirely possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT 
   pp.*,
   CASE
     WHEN exists (
         SELECT 
          * 
         FROM 
          friends_approvals fa  
         WHERE 
          fa.from_user_id = pp.user_id AND
          fa.persona_id = pp.id AND
          fa.to_user_id = 2
          )
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
   END as is_approved

 FROM 
   personas_personas pp 
 WHERE 
   pp.user_id=1
```

Or, depending on your taste:

```
 SELECT 
   pp.*,
   CASE
     WHEN fa.from_user_id IS NOT NULL
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
   END as is_approved

 FROM 
   personas_personas pp 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN friends_approvals fa ON
       pp.user_id = fa.from_user_id AND
       pp.id = fa.persona_id AND
       fa.to_user_id = 2
 WHERE 
   pp.user_id=1
```

Comment: That general approach would work, but some of the details of your query don't seem right to me. In particular, I don't think we can ignore `friends_approvals.persona_id`.

Comment: Hi Jake, thanks! This didn't work at first. But I added this: "AND fa.persona_id=pp.id"

Comment: yeah, I just updated my answer to include that, after reading @ruakh's comment

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your needs correctly, you can do this:

```
SELECT personas_personas.*,
       CASE WHEN friends_approvals IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS is_approved
  FROM personas_personas
  LEFT
 OUTER
  JOIN friends_approvals
    ON friends_approvals.from_user_id = ...
   AND friends_approvals.to_user_id = personas_personas.user_id
   AND friends_approvals.persona_id = personas_personas.id
 WHERE personas_personas.user_id = ...
;
```

That will find every `personas_personas` record with the specified `user_id`, together with an indicator of whether that user, in that persona, has been "approved" by a specified `from_user_id`.

(If that's *not* what you want, then please clarify!)